# HTTPS problem with Tor Browser Bundle 3.5

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, https

I've noticed after running Tor Browser Bundle 3.5 for a few minutes that it will refuse the connection to HTTPS websites. When I turn off HTTPS Everywhere then change a URL from HTTPS to HTTP the connection works again.

For example, after a few minutes I cannot connect to `https://www.torproject.org`, but without HTTPS Everywhere I can connect to `http://www.torproject.org`.

Does anyone else have this problem or it is only me? Does anyone know why or what might cause this problem? Is it a bug?

Comment: Do you still encounter problems with HTTPS sites?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like OP was hitting a bad exit relay. There has been some recent efforts to scan for such exits and flag them BadExit so they don't get used, but this will always be an occasional problem since new volunteer exit nodes can be added at any time. If this happens again, try selecting New Identity from the Tor Browser onion menu (or sending Tor the NEWNYM command some other way).